# Convert Html to show like a String

Tags: angular, httpwebrequest, text-editor, htmltext

I am inserting data from `QUILL text editor`, which is stored in HTML format. When I access the data to show somewhere it is showing same as HTML, I need that to show as normal text.

`<div class="card p-3 mb-3" [innerHTML]="mcq.question ">`

JSON from DB:

```
0:
answer: "&lt;p>mcq-1 A&lt;/p>"
question: "&lt;p>mcq-1\tQ&lt;/p>"
```

[image: my output is like this which has to be converted to normal text]

Answer (score 0):

This function will do the work:

```js
function decodeSpecialEntitiesHtml(html) {
  const str = document.createElement("textarea");
  str.innerHTML = html;
  return str.value;
}

var html = '&lt;p>mcq-1 A&lt;/p>'

document.getElementById('withoutFunction').innerText = html;
document.getElementById('withFunction').innerText = decodeSpecialEntitiesHtml(html);
```

```html
<label>without func:</label><div id="withoutFunction"></div>
<br>
<label>with func:</label><div id="withFunction"></div>
<br>
```

So you can use it like:

```
<div class="card p-3 mb-3" [innerText]="decodeSpecialEntitiesHtml(mcq.question)">
```

Because you want HTML to behave like text. So basically it is a text that is look like a html. so bind it with `innerText`.

---

### TypeScript

The typescript-friendly function will be:

```
public decodeSpecialEntitiesHtml(html) {
  const str = document.createElement("textarea");
  str.innerHTML = html;
  return str.value;
}
```

and use it in template like:

```
<div [innerText]="decodeSpecialEntitiesHtml(serverHtmlResponse)"></div>
```

Comment: these javascript throwing me error in Angluar

Comment: not working for me... The data which i get from Http is itself a HTML..
question: "&lt;p>sdfsdtryt&lt;/p>"
like this

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that the HTML is simply not valid. Are you sure that it's formatted correctly?

Another possibility: have you tried marking the HTML as safe using The [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml)? Depending on the type of tags that are used, Angular may stop it from rendering to prevent XSS attacks.

Note: only do this when you are 100% sure that the HTML is safe.

Comment: i will make it simple... I am getting the api data in HTML format.. So the HTML has to be executed as like in the browser to be shown in my div.. thats the thing